# make search in Observable sync

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, typescript, observable

I want to check, if given clientName is present in Observable Collection, but in cause of async run, i don't get "false" return at all. How to transform my function to sync - i would like not to use callbacks - just return true/false

```
checkIfClientNameIsUnique(clientName: string): boolean {
    var isUnique = true;
    this.getAll()
        .subscribe(clients => {
            clients.forEach(client => {
                if (clientName == client.name) {
                    isUnique = false
                }
            })
        });
    return isUnique
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see three options:

1. make checkIfClientNameIsUnique to return Promise then you
   can use it like checkIfClientNameIsUnique(name).then(isUnique =>
   {...})
2. Load all clients to array on initial state. I suppose you have ClientsService there you can put clients array, then your
   checkIfClientNameIsUnique method can be sync and use already loaded
   clients array.

3.If you emit to ES6 you can use async await keywords and it will look like this.

```
checkIfClientNameIsUnique(clientName: string): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.getAll()
            .subscribe(clients => {
                for (let client of clients) {
                    if (clientName == client.name) {
                        resolve(false);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                resolve(true);
            });
    });
}
// ...

async main() {
   let isUnique = await checkIfClientNameIsUnique(name);
}
```

Comment: how to transform checkIfClientNameIsUnique body into a Promise? the problem i have is to send this.getAll() parameter to the Promise body

Comment: I added example to my answer, let me know it it works :)

Comment: is any way to make it async without ECMA6? Or use it like you mentioned in point 1?

Comment: Typescript 2.1 will allows to use async await with ES5 but it is not ready yet :( You can see it in road map https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap

Comment: @Avocado20 now you can install Typescript 2.1 using npm `npm install -g typescript@next`